# Vb.NET Windows Forms Focus Event

Tags: vb.net, winforms, forms

I am working with .Net Windows Forms application (vb.net), 
I have Two Forms,

- **Form A** = Main form
- **Form B** = Which is being called by clicking a button on Form A

The Issue is, I want to update certain Controls(List,Grids) when ever my ***Form A gets Activated***,
At Form_A_Load it will load controls one must, but when I open Form B and upon Exit of Exit of Form B, I want to reload Form A's controls(List,Grids).

I have tried many events

Activated,Deactivated,Enter,Leave,Enabled,Visibility changed , but could not trap any,
If I am using Activated/Deactivated with some flag to check which was triggered, then a continues loop occurs.  Kindly some body suggest , the workable method

Here is the Edit code:

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub Form1_Activated(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Activated
    MessageBox.Show("Activated")
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Deactivate(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Deactivate
    ' MessageBox.Show("Deactivated")
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Me.Text = "Activated/Deactivated"
    MessageBox.Show("This will set focus lost")
End Sub
```

End Class
--If a once click on Button1_Click .. **"MessageBox.Show("Activated")"** appears again and again.

Comment: what do you mean you `want to reload Form A's controls`? cant you add such code to FormA_Activate?

Comment: I Did, but Activates calls again and again, even you click on a button ,

Comment: Form_activated fires when that user comes back to that form; I dont follow what you are saying about over and over with a button without code.  Do you want something to happen *just* when they close Form B?  Use a public property for that.

Comment: Your claim is wrong. The Activated event doesn't fire when you click a button on a currently-focused form. It fires only when one of the controls on the form receives the input focus after having lost it. The Activated event is the one you want. Post repro code if you still can't make it work.

Comment: @Cody Gray: I have this scenario, Tell me how to avoid looping, Below I have uploaded test project, kindly suggest..http://www.yourfilelink.com/get.php?fid=973728

Comment: I don't download files posted by random people online. Neither do most other people. The code to reproduce the problem should have been posted in your question. Use the [edit] link.

Comment: @Cody Gray :There is no way out here to post the ful working code, so i have uploaded to a random free file_repository.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, It was something multiple forms opened, and what I did is that at the FormClosing of last Form where my code Returns to Forma A, I have checked through Loop the Opened Forms and from there I selected my Form A and Triggered the Function Which Reloads the List.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**[UPDATED]**

```
Public Class FormA

Friend WithEvents objectFormB As FormB

Private Sub objectFormB_FormClosed(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosedEventArgs) Handles objectFormB.FormClosed
    'do whatever...
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Ups, sorry I edited my answer: Form1 would be your Form A, and Form 2 = Form B, So you have to declare a Form B object in your Form A using "Friend WithEvents" and add the event as well in your Form A object

Comment: Form A has two UserControls on it Form User Control_1 I am calling Form B, so I cannot figure out

Comment: Please post your code so that I can try to help you.